# Dropdown list implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

[image]

How can I implement a drop down list on button click like in the image?

Comment: it is a custom view (pop-up) with table added on the View on the button action.. by adjusting the pop-up view frame with arrow added.

Comment: review this link may be helped ....
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541736/dropdown-list-implemntation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541736/dropdown-list-implemntation

Comment: @VikasRajput it showing my question page only

Comment: @iosdev look ajaysharma and vikasRajput Answer and try it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes it look really like a dropdownlist. Here is a code I used for creating one.For this first import the  framework,make the dynamic view and add the background image.and after add the table in the dynamic view.

```
-(IBAction)DropDownTable:(id)sender
    {
        UIView *BackGrView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];

        BackGrView.hidden = NO;
        if(TableView.frame.origin.y ==203)
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
            [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 204, 27, 160)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            [self.view TableView];
        }

        else if (TableView.frame.origin.y == 204)
        {
            [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 203, 27, 0)];
            BackGrView.hidden = YES;
        }

        [self.view addSubview:TableActivityLevel];
    }
```

Comment: @VikasSRajput Could you please tell me what is `TableActivityLevel` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think below links would be useful to achieve with some modifications. Please go through the links below :

1. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/zpopovercontroller
2. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tspopover
3. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover

Here `UITableView` is used for displaying popover. You can implement a `Section` methods for `TableView` to achieve the same effect that you want.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with Custom View.For your reference,I can show you the steps for its implementation:

1. Take UIView using the popup animation & add a UITableView within it
   having the popover kind of image in its background.Fix this image
   with Arrow at top which will give it similar effect as actual
   UIPopOverController.
2. Create Custom header of the UITableView.
3. Secondly, change the color of UIView to the light gray.
4. Manage the PopUp/displaying & Dismissing/Hiding of this UIView
   accordingly with animation.

Answer (score -2):

While clicking that button, show (Sectioned Table View) `UITableview` as shown in figure (hope you know about creating `UITableView`) and then load your listview contents using `cellForRowIndex` delegate. While selecting the row of the table, you can get the value and hide UITableView in `didselectrowatIndexPath` delegate.